# set status command doesn't set status

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, replit

This should change the status and activity but for some reason, it only changes the status not the activity.

```js
const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/);
const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

if (command == "status") {
    if (!args[2]) {
        return message.channel.send({ content: "Usuage: {prefix}{command} {online/idle etc} {type} {status}" });
    }

    client.user.setPresence({
        status: `${args[0]}`,
        activities: [{ type: `${args[1]}`, name: `${args.slice(2).join(" ")}` }],
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using v12:

```js
if(!args[2]){ return message.channel.send({ content: 'Usuage: {prefix}{command} {online/idle etc} {type} {status}' }) }

client.user.setPresence({
  status: `${args[0]}`,
  activity: { type: `${args[1].toUpperCase()}`, name: `${args.slice(2).join(' ')}` }
});
```

And if you're using v13:

```js
if(!args[2]){ return message.channel.send({ content: 'Usuage: {prefix}{command} {online/idle etc} {type} {status}' }) }

client.user.setPresence({
  status: `${args[0]}`,
  activities: [{ type: `${args[1].toUpperCase()}`, name: `${args.slice(2).join(' ')}` }]
});
```

Make sure that `args[1]` is in caps (e.g: `PLAYING`, `WATCHING`)
Note that bots cannot set a `CUSTOM` activity type, it is only for custom statuses received from users

Comment: I tried this but same problem, when I use the command it changes the status, not the type. So when I do .status idle playing nothing it becomes idle, but there's no type/activity

Comment: I edited the solution. Try and see if it works now

Comment: sorry but it's still the same problem

Comment: That's odd. Can you log `args[1].toUpperCase()` and see what it returns?

Comment: omfg nvm I was using v13 but I'm on v12. thanks bro it worked